# A book about a Prince, a Kingdom of Salt and Narwhals

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm pretty sure the cover of the book was blue, with a picture of a porthole on it. I remember there being a normal boy who became a prince, or perhaps he was a prince from the start who became a king. I remember a voyage via submarine (made of salt?) to a kingdom of salt below the water. I also remember something about narwhals, oddly enough.

I may have bought it at a scholastic book fair around 2004.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! See [how to ask a good story-ID for some suggestions to improve this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999). For starters **when were you a kid?** If you are 20, we'd be searching a very different time period from if you are a 300-year-old vampire :P

Comment: The other three books sound like public domain works, and it's not uncommon for someone to market reprints of those classics as a set. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any hits.

Comment: The only public-domain children's book I can think of that has narwhals in it is Charles Kingsley's "The Water Babies." But that doesn't have a boy becoming a prince/king, nor a submarine or kingdom of salt. So that's not the answer.